# Python GRPC How to reuse channel correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, grpc, grpc-python

I am writing a GRPC python client to communicate with a GRPC server as below.

```
class GrpcClient:
    """
    Class to send request to Grpc server.
    """

    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        self._server_address = host + ':' + str(port)
        with grpc.insecure_channel(self._server_address) as channel:
            self._stub = MyServerStub(channel)

    def invoke_method(self, request):
        response = self._stub.process(request)
        logging.info("response received: " + str(response))
```

This result in error **ValueError: Cannot invoke RPC on closed channel!** since the channel was getting closed on **int** I modified as below

```
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        self._server_address = host + ':' + str(port)
        channel = grpc.insecure_channel(self._server_address)
        self._stub = MyServerStub(channel)
```

Now both the channel and stub gets reused but my worry is that the channel might not be closed which might lead into memory leak

To prevent it I tried opening the channel and creating stub on each request which is expensive.

Can anyone suggest a way of reusing channel and stub without any leak?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could tackle this problem, which are not necessarily mutually exclusive. The first is proxying the channel's `close` method to your class and requiring your class's user to call it. That would look something like this:

```py
class GrpcClient:
  def __init_(self, ...):
    self._channel = grpc.insecure_channel(...)
    self._stub = MyServerStub(self._channel)

  def close(self):
    self._channel.close()
```

To make this API a bit cleaner, you could provide a context manager API similar to what `grpc.Channel` does:

```py
class GrpcClient:
  ...
  def __enter__(self):
    return self
  
  def __exit_(self, ...):
    self.close()
```

Then you can use your class like

```
with GrpcClient(...) as client:
  for task in tasks:
    do_work(client, task)
```

People have attempted to use `__del__` to automatically call such cleanup methods in the past, but we've found that the guarantees provided by CPython about when and if this method will be called are too weak to provide anything resembling C++ RAII, so we're left with manual options like I outlined above.

Comment: The second solution does not solves the problem it just delegates the problem to the caller of the API and would be expensive since each call would result setup and destroy channel.

Comment: The question was "How to reuse channel correctly". My answer is the prescribed usage of a channel in the gRPC Python package. The expectation is that you maintain a reference to the channel for as long as it is needed, so your client would need to be a long-lived object that is used multiple times. If this is unacceptable to you, there is experimental support for stub invocation without explicit creation of a channel. Take a look at this example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/fc66bb707b4baf070fbee087e7d1cd271fa02727/examples/python/no_codegen/greeter_client.py#L37